# Set initial value of datepicker input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I'm using the jQuery UI `datepicker`

I need to put the start date automatically in the input type text.

```
$(function() {
  $("#datepicker").datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'DD, d MM, yy'
  }).bind("change", function() {
    var minValue = $(this).val();
    minValue = $.datepicker.parseDate("DD, d MM, yy", minValue);
    minValue.setDate(minValue.getDate());
    $("#datepicker").datepicker("option", "minDate", minValue);
  })
});
```

Comment: Is your goal that the input is filled with the current date? Or what do you want to achieve?

Comment: How does this not work as expected?

Comment: What should the start date be? right now your `minDate` depends on the value of the input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set a variable containing your start date, in my case it's the current date.

The set the `minDate` (or `defaultDate`) of the datepicker upon initialization.
Then you can set the value of the `input` using your start date.

```js
$(function() {
  var startDate = new Date();
  $("#datepicker").datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'DD, d MM, yy',
    minDate: startDate
  }).bind("change", function() {
    var minValue = $(this).val();
    minValue = $.datepicker.parseDate("DD, d MM, yy", minValue);
    minValue.setDate(minValue.getDate());
    $("#datepicker").datepicker("option", "minDate", minValue);
  }).val($.datepicker.formatDate("DD, d MM, yy", startDate));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css"
<p>Date:
  <input type="text" id="datepicker">
</p>
```